# Accessing text files with Javascript in a chrome app

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome-app

I would like to be able to edit and save text files in javascript, like the code below, but I have to be able to do it without using system.io, as this is a chrome app. Is there any way to be able to do this?

```
import System.IO;
var filePath = "data.txt";

function Start() {
    if (!File.Exists(filePath)) {
        CreateFile();
    }
}

function CreateFile() {
    var sw: StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath);
    sw.WriteLine("Hello World")
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
    print("Done");
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/text-editor?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html you can use node.js fs

Comment: No, I haven't, but I will start doing so now, thank you.

Comment: There is one way if you want to create file than you can done it using ajax, make file edit code on server language and call tha using ajax

Comment: Thanks @mvermand, that should work.

Comment: @LegusX I added a snippet in a separate answer to get you going

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are creating a chrome app, you can use `chrome.fileSystem`.

This snippet comes from the chrome app samples:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/text-editor

```
function openFile() {
  chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry(function (entry) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      showError(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      return;
    }
    clearError();
    setEntry(entry, false);
    replaceDocContentsFromFileEntry();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, JavaScript has no access to local files. It can only access the HTML document. To access external files, such as text files, you must use VBScript. Note that VBScript only works on IE and Edge browsers, and only when they are enabled in the browser's settings.

Comment: As far as I know Chrome-apps can access files on the file system, as long as a user explicitly opens them with the open file dialog... which seems fine for an editor

Comment: As the OP has mentioned that this is a Chrome App, they can use the [fileSystem api](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) to read/write to local filesystem. The only thing required is asking the user for permission to use folder/file.